# Can not install linux off of a YUMI UEFI multiboot USB

Tags: linux, usb, yumi

I can't install Manjaro Linux off of my YUMI UEFI USB. My USB has Ubuntu, Manjaro XCFE, Manjaro Gnome, Tails, Kali Linux, and Windows on it. I'm using a 32gb SanDisk Cruzer blade drive for my ISOs with USB persistence on.

This is the error I get when I try to install manjaro after it gets to around 2%

[image: 1]

Comment: This question requires a lot more details. "Can't install" says nothing (and no, having two different ISOs/version of Manjaro ISN'T the problem). Please [edit] accordingly by describing what happens when you try to boot the live session and/or installation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I attached a picture of the error I get

Comment: At this point I can only suggest redoing the USB stick with a freshly downloaded and verified ISO.